# what's the point in growing up "good" and "bad"?

Tags: the-sims-2

When your sim grows up a balloon appears and it gives you a score. However I fail to figure out what are the consequences of such score on the gameplay.

The only growing-up score which seems important is the one assigned from adult to elder age, as it has a direct impact on the lifespan left.

Are there any other effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Growing up" is a particularly strong memory, and sims who have grown up poorly (due to aspiration failure) will spend the first couple of days in their new age moping about it while a picture of the bad memory appears in their thought bubbles.

Accordingly, because this is a negative memory, growing up badly will allow sims to learn, and then gossip about, the event.

The "score" is just a numerical representation of the aspiration bar, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe growing up good will let you have more positive traits as you get older.

Comment: That's in Sims 3.

Comment: Then it is you get extra "aspiration" slots i think.

Comment: Nope; that's for passing the first and final years College.